# Can I apply more than 1 transparency to one object in CorelDRAW?

Tags: transparency, corel-draw

I have a background image with linear transparency applied on the top of my image. I would like to replicate the same transparency on the bottom of the image.  How can I do this?

[image: image example]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do this. Click on the image and then click on **interactive transparency tool**.

After that, click on **edit transparency** on the top left corner

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN52K.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Basically to my understanding, when you select the image, select your interactive transparency tool. Apply to where you want it to be transparent, and then convert it to bitmap. But remember you can make it transparent countless times as long as you're converting it to bitmap after each apply.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer specifically for Corel Draw, but in other vector software, what I'd usually do is use an object on top that has a gradient.

So, I'd place a square shape on top of the map, and then use a gradient of white->transparent->white

Granted, that only works if you intend to have a white background at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can Add or Set Transparency to more then one object.

1. Select object
2. Go to <kbd>Effects > Lens > Transparency</kbd>
3. Set rate
4. Set Color
5. Click `Frozen`

Works Like Photoshop.